# WPF (MVVM) delete item from Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created the ViewModel class which return an istance of XmlDataProvider, i bind to it in here in the ListBox, a DeleteCommand (ICommand).

```
   <ListBox x:Name="Books" Margin="0,0,0,10"    
                     DataContext="{Binding DataProvider}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding}"                      
                     SelectionMode="Single">
   </ListBox>

 <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}">Remove item</Button>
```

The listbox load the XML's data and the button execute the DeleteCommand just fine.

My Xml is like this and the DataProvider XPath = "Books/Book":

```
<Books>
   <Book Id="1">The book</Book>
   ...
</Books>
```

The problem is i cannot even figure out how to get back the item selected in the list. My goal is to get the id into the ViewModel or bind it to the button and pass it as a paramter but i don't see how.

Anybody can help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CommandParameter :

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Books Path=SelectedItem}">Remove item</Button>
```

This way you will have your SelectedItem passed to your method.

Comment: hi, i tried this way at the begin but apparently is not binding to the SelectedItem. If i understood correctly is because i set DataContext="{Binding DataProvider}" in the ListBox. I tried then to create a normal Listbox with embedded ListBoxItems and in that case SelectedItem binds fine in fact

Comment: Oh right, then you could try to remove the SelectedItem item part, and just do :
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Books, Path=SelectedItem}">Remove item</Button>